# how to compare the prediction of two models using statistical significant test python

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python

basically I have the age prediction from one model:

```
df_baseline    userid|y_pred
                 12  |29
                 13  |35
                 14  |32 
                 15  |39
                 (more data)
```

and I have the prediction from second model:

```
df_final       userid|age
                 12  |31
                 13  |34
                 14  |32 
                 15  |21
                 (more data)
```

how can I run a statistical significance test to check that df_final model performs significantly better than the baseline prediction?

I thought about using Null hypothesis testing but I know this one checks if the two samples are significantly different or not so I am lost what to do here

Comment: Do you have only model predictions or do you have the actual age as well? If you don't have the truth, then you can only compare the model to say whether they tend to agree or not. Even if they agree with each other they might be wrong about the age.

Comment: @dipetkov so the baseline data is the data that I am comparing the df_final age to. so you could say that the baseline is the truth that I am comparing my df_final to and I want to check that my model(df_final) is significantly better than (baseline_data)

Comment: But is baseline_data generated by a baseline model or is the truth?

Comment: @dipetkov so I was given the baseline_data and was asked to generate a prediction of the age and I did (which is the df_final) and then was asked to run a statistically signifincant test to prove that my model (df_final) performs better than the baseline_data that they gave me

Comment: By now you may agree with me, or not, that you should go back and ask for clarification what the task is. If you assume baseline_data is the truth, then you can come up with some measure of how well new model performs on baseline data. But to compare *two* models, you actually need *three* inputs: truth, predictions from model 1 and predictions from model 2.

Comment: PS: Statistical tests are not statistically significant but once we perform a test we might get results that are statistically significant.

Comment: @dipetkov yea I agree with you but if we assume for now that the baseline is the truth, how can I perform a stastically significance test to come up with a conclusion of how well my new model is doing? one thing I thought of doind is t-test by getting the p value and if the p-value is less than 0.05 I'd assume that my model is doing better than the baseline what do you think?

Comment: You seem to not be able to give up on the idea that there is a way to measure that your model is better than the baseline model. Not without knowing the truth. Better means closer to the truth.

Comment: And if you assume that baseline_data is the truth, no you cannot do better than the truth. In that case you can evaluate performance in terms of mean squared error or similar.